# initialise the NSwindowcontroller in maximised form in OSX

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindowcontroller

Is there a way to initialise the NSwindow controller in maximised form/full screen?i came across some function but it was deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

Something you can do in your `NSViewController` subclass is this:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    override func viewWillAppear() {
        view.window?.zoom(self)
    }
}
```

Note though that this kind of behaviour may not be what your users expect. Specially if your window is a regular window that they can position and resize. Normally the user preferred window size and position are persisted and restored between app usages.